# Why isn't my program detecting the words "Address:" or "Professional:" here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I'm attempting to search plain texts in this configuration:

```
Named H Man, MBA
Personal: 
Address: 
Professional: 
0000 Something St 
Apt 000 
City, ST 12345-6789 
No Business Contact Information. 
Academic: 
2019 Bachelors, Education - AF s
```

My goal is to retrieve just the first portion of the address in this text, the parts "0000 Something St" and "Apt 000". This is complicated by the fact that some of the entries in the plaintext are configured differently, so I'm using a more general method: I'm attempting to find the lines that contain the word "Address:" or "Professional:" to get the line that starts the portion of the text that I want, and then find whatever line after that that contains a comma as the end. After this works, I'll write code to remove everything I don't need from those lines afterward. Most of the texts work with the program as written--only this one isn't outputting anything, which I think is because it isn't detecting the words "Address:" or "Professional:" correctly for some reason.

The code I've written so far is this, plus a method of outputting them afterward that can't be the problem:

```
def FindAddress(person):
    global address
    address = "NA"
    addressUncropped = ""
    lineBeforeAddress = 0
    lineAfterAddress = 0
    personLines = person.splitlines()
    wordList = []
    lineIndex = 0
    for line in personLines:  # This sets up the before and after markers to be used later
        wordList = line.split(" ")
        for word in wordList:
            print(word)
            if word == "Address:" or word == "Professional:" and lineBeforeAddress == 0:
                lineBeforeAddress = lineIndex
            if "," in line and lineAfterAddress == 0 and lineIndex >= lineBeforeAddress:
                lineAfterAddress = lineIndex+1
        lineIndex += 1
    for line in personLines[lineBeforeAddress:lineAfterAddress]:  # This uses the before and after markers to get the address
        addressUncropped += line
```

If you have any other unrelated advice that might help with this task, I'd also like to hear that. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may need parentheses here: `if (word == "Address:" or word == "Professional:") and lineBeforeAddress == 0:`. But it depends on the exact logic that you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this condition is true on the first line:

```
if "," in line and lineAfterAddress == 0 and lineIndex >= lineBeforeAddress:
```

The first line contains a comma in `Named H Man, MBA`. `lineAfterAddress` and `lineBEforeAddress` are both zero, so `lineIndex >= lineBeforeAddress` is true. You need to check that `lineBeforeAddress` has been set, so you also need the condition `lineBeforeAddress > 0`.

Also, this test shouldn't be in the `for word in wordList` loop, since it's just testing the whole line, not individual words.

The loop at the end can be simplified to:

```
addressUncropped = "".join(personLines[lineBeforeAddress:lineAfterAddress])
```

Full code:

```
def FindAddress(person):
    global address
    address = "NA"
    addressUncropped = ""
    lineBeforeAddress = 0
    lineAfterAddress = 0
    personLines = person.splitlines()
    wordList = []
    lineIndex = 0
    for line in personLines:  # This sets up the before and after markers to be used later
        wordList = line.split(" ")
        for word in wordList:
            if (word == "Address:" or word == "Professional:") and lineBeforeAddress == 0:
                lineBeforeAddress = lineIndex
        if "," in line and lineAfterAddress == 0 and lineBeforeAddress > 0 and lineIndex >= lineBeforeAddress:
            lineAfterAddress = lineIndex+1
        lineIndex += 1
    addressUncropped = "".join(personLines[lineBeforeAddress:lineAfterAddress])
    return addressUncropped
```